# htaccess for missing 404 images in Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Trying to figure out the best way to show a missing image default image if the image does not exist to prevent 404's. I added an htaccess call that would display an image that if the image cannot be found but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is in the public directory and the img folder is also inside the public folder.

```
<FilesMatch ".(jpg|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "img/no-image-available.gif"
</FilesMatch>
```

Full htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/img/no-image-available.gif"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What application server do you use? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: Apache. But may also switch to Nginx one day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In regex dot needs to be escaped.
2. `ErrorDocument` needs absolute path to default image so it must start with `/`

You can try this code in your .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/img/no-image-available.gif"
</FilesMatch>
```

**Update:** Keep this code just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /img/no-image-available.gif [L,NC]
```

Comment: Still not working. I can't figure out another way to get this to work.

Comment: Does this .htaccess also have other code? If yes then post in the question so that I can investigate & suggest.

Comment: ok move this `<FilesMatch>` on top of .htaccess before all other code.

Comment: ok check updated rule. This goes just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Still nothing. I even went as far as adding the image to the public root(where the htaccess file is) and still nothing

Comment: But how are you testing it?

Comment: refreshing the browser? Not sure if I need to restart the server each time or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58452/discussion-between-anubhava-and-lynx).

Comment: Actually I think it's working. It must have been a cache issue or something. I cleared it and it seems to be working. It's not working for every image but that could still be cached related

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured in apache2.conf that you have AllowOverride set to All?

The default is set to None which means your .htaccess will be ignored in this case.

Example for Apache on Ubuntu server

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I changed the settings in httpd.conf and restarted apache and that didn't work. I didn't see a apache2.conf file. I am using wamp if that helps.